# Symfony 1 create a view cache files before user visits the page

Tags: php, caching, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

After clearing the cache, is there any way to create a view cache files before user visits the page? Currently we are using the below command which creates a few of the cache files but not the view ones.

```
symfony cache:prime --env=qa frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to generate cache files before a user visits the page.  You need to create a cache warm-up script.  A simple curl command to each URL will create the cache files:

```
curl http://myapp.example.com/user/action/
```

Another option is to create a PHP script, and using Symfony's built-in browser that is normally used for testing, you can use it for warming up your cache, like this example:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'staging', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration);

// Array of URLs to browse
$pages = array(
  '/foo/index',
  '/foo/bar/id/1',
  ...
);

$b = new sfBrowser();
foreach ($pages as $page)
{
  $b->get($page);
}
```

There is more information here http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/18-Performance under the **Generating Cached Pages** section and more information about caching is here http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/12-Caching